# Pronouncing double "o" in Foot vs. Cooperation

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, vowels

Why are the two words **"foot"** and **"cooperation"** so different in pronunciation?

Comment: Maybe because co- is just a prefix. So the actual pronounciation for operation should still be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will often see "cooperation" written as "co-operation", reflecting its origins as "operation" with the prefix "[co-](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/co-)". This explains the pronunciation, which is just the sum of the pronunciation of the two parts.

As for the difference in pronunciation between words like "book", "boot" and "floor", there's a thread [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36905/why-are-there-3-different-ways-to-pronounce-oo) that might help.

Answer (score 2):

"Cooperative" is pronounced as if "co-operative" was still two separate words, but without any noticeable pause between them.

Some traditionalists spell "coöperative" with a special accent mark to indicate that the two consecutive "o"s have different pronunciations.  (In this context, this "ö" does not indicate the sound of a German *umlaut*.)  Most Americans are completely unfamiliar with this orthography.

When it is abbreviated to "Co-op" or "Coop", two pronunciations are common.

- Most Americans pronounce "Co-op" as if it were spelled "coöp".
- On the other hand, the "[Harvard Cooperative Society](https://store.thecoop.com/comprehensivehistory/)" is the college bookstore chain that serves Harvard and MIT.  In this context, "Cooperative" is pronounced as if it were spelled "Coöperative".  In typical conversation, "The Coop" refers to either a store in the chain, or the whole chain.  In this context, "Coop" is pronounced as a single syllable, just like "coop" in "chicken coop" or "cooper".  Its "oo" sound can be found in "boot", not "foot".